# can I use Text as value to write to context in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a scenario to calculate average of two columns in map reduce. So what I did is, I have got the values from file using mapper and concatenated them as Text then tried to write them to Context like below.

```html
class TestMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
  private Text outputKey;
  private Text outputVal;


  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  
  //more code here

context.write(outputkey,OutputVal);


    
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use Text as value in fact you can use any other data type supported by the Hadoop framework. Are you getting any issues? if yes, share your code and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the concern Azim. I got it worked by changing the data types in job object.

Comment: It would be better if you can read Oreilly's Hadoop: The Definitive Guide book. Its awesome. Great your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a custom data type here e.g. a TextPair class which has two Text elements to store the data you need. Below is a sample code that is used to output a pair of Strings in value of mapper context.

```
// Mapper's map code
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, TextPair>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();
    String year = line.substring(15, 19);
    int airTemperature;
    if (line.charAt(87) == '+') { // parseInt doesn't like leading plus signs
      airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
    } else {
      airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
    }
    String quality = line.substring(92, 93);
    if (airTemperature != MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")) {
        System.out.println("Year "+year+" "+airTemperature);
      context.write(new Text(year), new TextPair(String.valueOf(airTemperature),1));
    }
```

// Text Pair - Custom Data type code below

```
public class TextPair implements WritableComparable<TextPair> {

private Text first;
private Text second;

//Default constructor is a must
public TextPair() {
    this.first=new Text();
    this.second=new Text();
}

public TextPair(String first,int second) {
    try {
        this.first=new Text(first);
        this.second=new Text(String.valueOf(second));
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred "+ex.getCause());
    }

}

// Other methods such as compare, equals, hashcode, write, readFields etc implementation also needs to done

public Text getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public Text getSecond() {
    return second;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.first+"\t"+this.second+"\t";
}

}
```

If you need still more details refer Hadoop Definitive Guide. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Pushkin, I have followed the logic you specified. But I am getting same type of error. I have referred Definitive guide book. But it is not working for me.

Comment: I am getting error like this.                                                                    Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable, received TextPair

Comment: I have seen this happen when in the Job code (where you configure mapper and reducer), output type has been mentioned differently from what is actually being output from mapper. Also it would be helpful if you can share your complete code for Job, Mapper and Reducer.

Comment: This worked perfectly. And th we need not use TextPair in my case. That can be done with Text itself.   Thanks a lot for your help.